# Is $\lfloor \sin(x) \rfloor$ a continuous function?

Tags: limits, functions

Taking the limit of $\lfloor\sin x \rfloor$ as $x$ approaches $0$, I get $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \lfloor\sin x \rfloor = -1$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \lfloor\sin x \rfloor  = 0$, but WolframAlpha says that this function is continuous over $\mathbb R$. So, is this function really continuous?

Comment: No, it is not. Can you show your Alpha query ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oddly enough, if you go to WolframAlpha and type "floor(sin(x)) continuous, it does claim that the function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, despite also displaying a graph which shows jump discontinuities.

Comment: $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is notoriously discontinuous at integers, and $\sin x$ takes a few integer values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a function $f(x)$ to be continuous at a point $x_0$ in its domain, three conditions must hold:

1. $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x)$ exists,
2. $f(x_0)$ exists, and
3. $f(x_0) = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}$

Clearly, $\lfloor \sin(x) \rfloor$ violates the first condition, since the limits from the left and right-hand sides don't agree.

Comment: If this function is not continous, does it mean that it is also not periodic?

Comment: @edionz No, not at all. $\sin(x + 2\pi) = \sin(x)$, so $\lfloor\sin(x + 2\pi)\rfloor = \lfloor\sin(x)\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lfloor f \rfloor$ is only continuous if it is constant, which only happens if $c \leq f < c + 1$  for some $c$.
Therefore, $\lfloor \sin \rfloor$ is not continuous.
Here is a plot from Wolfram Alpha which shows the discontinuities:

[image]